# std::ostringstream isn't returning a valid string

Tags: c++, winapi, std, ostringstream

I'm trying to use std::ostringstream to convert a number into a string (char *), but it doesn't seem to be working. Here's the code I have:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream out;
    out << 1234;

    const char *intString = out.str().c_str();

    MessageBox(NULL, intString, intString, MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);

    return 0;
}
```

The resulting message box simply has no text in it.

This leads me to believe that the call to `out.str().c_str()` is returning an invalid string, but I'm not sure. Since I've trimmed this program down so far an am still getting the problem, I must have made an embarrassingly simple mistake. Help is appreciated!

Comment: +1 for the clear, concise question that includes a SSCCE. I get the proper text in windows 7 with GCC 4.7.1, though.

Comment: @chris : Undefined behavior is undefined. ;-]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`out.str()` returns a `std::string` *by value*, which means that you are calling `.c_str()` on a temporary. Consequently, by the time `intString` is initialized, it is already pointing at invalid (destroyed) data.

Cache the result of `.str()` and work with that:

```
std::string const& str = out.str();
char const* intString = str.c_str();
```

Comment: The `const&` looks mighty awkard. Why not just `const std::string mystring(out.str());`?

Comment: @rubenvb : What do you perceive to be the difference?

Comment: Hi ildjarn. I guess @rubenvb means: When a developer reads `const std::string str(out.str());` he immediately understands that `str` is a copy. But `const std::string& str = out.str();` gives the impression `str` is just a reference to a `string` handled by an other variable. The second case may be confusing, isn't it?

Comment: @olibre : The second case _is_ just a reference to a temporary... ;-]

Comment: Yep, I asked (yesterday) about [reference to an unnamed temporary object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267676) and I referred to your above answer. (Note: my question is not a duplicate of any other question on SO, the other question is about lifetime of function return object)  Now I understand this C++ trick :-) but it was not obvious! Cheers ;-)