# Temporary std::strings returning junk

Tags: c++

I'm still learning c++, so please bear with me.  I'm writing a simple wrapper around boost filesystem paths -- I'm having strange issues with returning temporary strings.  Here's my simple class (this is not exact, but pretty close):

```
typedef const char* CString;
typedef std::string String;
typedef boost::filesystem::path Path;

class FileReference {

    public:

        FileReference(const char* path) : mPath(path) {};

        // returns a path
        String  path() const {
            return mPath.string();
        };

        // returns a path a c string
        CString c_str() const {
            return mPath.string().c_str();
        };

    private:

        Path    mPath;

}
```

With the little test code below:

```
FileReference file("c:\\test.txt");

OutputDebugString(file.path().c_str()); // returns correctly c:\test.txt
OutputDebugString(file.c_str());        // returns junk (ie îþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþî.....)
```

I'm pretty sure this has to deal with temporaries, but I can't figure out why that would be -- shouldn't everything be copying correctly?

Comment: what's the source for `OutputDebugString()`?

Comment: Cringed at `typedef`'ing your own `CString`...

Comment: @OttoAllmendinger - It is a [Windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Comment: Related: [std::ostringstream isn't returning a valid string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11164982/636019)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `mPath.string()` returns a string by value. That temporary string object is destructed as soon as FileReference::c_str() returns, so its c_str() becomes invalid. With such a model, it's not possible to create a `c_str()` function without introducing some kind of class- or static-level variable for the string.

Consider the following alternatives:

```
//Returns a string by value (not a pointer!)
//Don't call it c_str() - that'd be misleading
String str() const
{             
     return mPath.string();
}
```

or

```
void str(String &s) const
{             
     s = mPath.string();
}
```

Comment: A valid use for the first suggestion would be `OutputDebugString(file.str().c_str());`

Answer (score 8):

```
CString c_str() const {
        return mPath.string().c_str();
    };
```

`mPath.string()` returns a copy of a `std::string`. That copy is stored in a temporary which will be destroyed at the end of this expression.

`.c_str()` returns a pointer to memory which will be destroyed when the string is destroyed, i.e. at the end of this expression.

You are returning a pointer to memory which is already destroyed.

Comment: @PermanentGuest - are you sure? I can't find `.c_str()` in the Boost.Filesystem [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Class-template-basic_path).

Comment: @Robᵩ : Those docs are nearly three years old. The [_current_ docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-native-format-observers) mention it. ;-] (This was probably added in FileSystem v3.)

Comment: @PermanentGuest I was getting a bug path.c_str(). I was only getting one character (as of boost 1_49)

Answer (score 0):

Expressions

```
OutputDebugString(file.path().c_str())
```

and

```
OutputDebugString(file.c_str())
```

are similar in that they both effectively call `c_str()` method on a temporary `std::string` object and attempt to use the result of that call. The first one calls it directly as `file.path().c_str()` subexpression. The second one does it more implicitly: inside `FileReference::c_str()` method.

In the first case the temporary `std::string` object is explicitly created by `file.path()` call as an immediate part of the entire expression. In accordance with the rules of the language the lifetime of that temporary object extends to the end of the whole expression, which is why the temporary and the result of `c_str()` call remain valid throughout.

In the second case the temporary `std::string` object is created inside `FileReference::c_str()` method. That temporary object is destroyed when this method returns, meaning that `FileReference::c_str()` returns a pointer to "dead" data. This is the reason for the "junk" in question.