# ShellExecuteEx doesn't pass long command

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

When I use ShellExecuteEx with such a command `"-unused parameter -action capturescreenshot -filename C:\\ATDK\\Screenshots\\abcd.jbg"` everything works fine and Executor.exe starts with `char* argv[]` having all the approx. 9 parameters. But when the command has for a couple symbols more, e.g. file name is "abc...xyz.jpg" then that process has argc == 1 and the command is empty. So the command is OK before sending to ShellExecute After I changed that to the ShellExecute, not Ex, it works! Command can be very long, and it's passed successfully. Can anybody explain what is the difference? Here's a code with the SHELLEXECUTEINFO I filled up.

```
std::wstringstream wss;
wss << L"-unused" << " "    // added because we need to pass some info as 0 parameter
    << L"parameter" << " "  // added because EU parser sucks
    << L"-action" << " "
    << L"capturescreenshot" << " "
    << L"-filename" << " "
    << L"C:\\ATDK\\Screenshots\\abc.jpg";

SHELLEXECUTEINFO shell_info;
ZeroMemory(&shell_info, sizeof(shell_info));

shell_info.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
shell_info.fMask = SEE_MASK_ASYNCOK | SEE_MASK_NO_CONSOLE;
shell_info.hwnd = NULL;
shell_info.lpVerb = NULL;
shell_info.lpFile = L"C:/ATDK/Executor";
shell_info.lpParameters = (LPCWSTR)wss.str().c_str();
shell_info.lpDirectory = NULL;
shell_info.nShow = SW_MINIMIZE;
shell_info.hInstApp = NULL;
// 1
ShellExecuteEx(&shell_info); 
// this sucks, 
// GetLastError returns err code 2147483658, 
//FormatMessage returns The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available

// 2 
ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, L"C:/ATDK/Executor", (LPCWSTR)wss.str().c_str(), NULL, NULL);
// OK!
```

Comment: That (LPCWSTR) cast only stopped the compiler from telling you the code was wrong, it did not stop you from doing it wrong.  If you don't want to convert to a Unicode string with mbstowcs() or MultiByteToWideString() then use SHELLEXECUTEINFOA and ShellExecuteExA().

Comment: You are also not checking for errors correctly. You have to examine the return value of the function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weird behavior while converting a std::string to a LPCSTR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370536/weird-behavior-while-converting-a-stdstring-to-a-lpcstr)

Comment: @HansPassant: The cast is always dubious, in this case however it's just needless. Had your initial analysis been right, changing `ShellExecuteEx` to `ShellExecute` wouldn't have fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your bug is here:

```
shell_info.lpParameters = (LPCWSTR)wss.str().c_str();
```

`wss.str()` returns a temporary object, that no longer exists after the end of the full expression in which it is created. Using it after that point is *undefined behavior*.

To solve this you will have to construct a `std::wstring` object, that lives long enough for the call to `ShellExecuteEx` to return.

```
std::wstringstream wss;
wss << L"-unused" << " "
    << L"parameter" << " "
    // ...

SHELLEXECUTEINFO shell_info;
ZeroMemory(&shell_info, sizeof(shell_info));

// Construct string object from string stream
std::wstring params{ wss.str() };

shell_info.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
shell_info.fMask = SEE_MASK_ASYNCOK | SEE_MASK_NO_CONSOLE;
shell_info.hwnd = NULL;
shell_info.lpVerb = NULL;
shell_info.lpFile = L"C:\\ATDK\\Executor";  // Path separator on Windows is \
shell_info.lpParameters = params.c_str();  // Use string object that survives the call
shell_info.lpDirectory = NULL;
shell_info.nShow = SW_MINIMIZE;
shell_info.hInstApp = NULL;

ShellExecuteEx(&shell_info);
```

Note that your second call

```
ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, L"C:\\ATDK\\Executor", wss.str().c_str(), NULL, NULL);
```

reliably works. Even though `wss.str()` still returns a temporary, it is valid until the end of the full expression (i.e. throughout the function call).