# Reference to an unnamed temporary object (life time)

Tags: c++, reference, temporary, object-lifetime

After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164982/stdostringstream-isnt-returning-a-valid-string/11165022#11165022) from [ildjarn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/636019), I wrote the following example, and it looks like an unnamed temporary object has the same life time as its reference!

- How come this is possible?
- Is it specified in the C++ standard?
- Which version?

**Source code:**

```
#include <iostream>  //cout
#include <sstream>   //ostringstream 

int main ()
{
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << 1234;

        std::string const& str = oss.str();
        char        const* ptr = str.c_str();

        // Change the stream content
        oss << "_more_stuff_";
        oss.str(""); //reset
        oss << "Beginning";
        std::cout << oss.str() <<'\n';

        // Fill the call stack
        // ... create many local variables, call functions...

        // Change again the stream content
        oss << "Again";
        oss.str(""); //reset
        oss << "Next should be '1234': ";
        std::cout << oss.str() <<'\n';

        // Check if the ptr is still unchanged
        std::cout << ptr << std::endl;
}
```

**Execution:**

```
> g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
> g++ main.cpp -O3
> ./a.out
Beginning
Next should be '1234':
1234
```

Comment: The fact that `const` references extend the lifetime of temporaries should be covered fairly on in your C++ book.

Comment: You should find your answer if you just try searching the web for the phrase you used: _temporary object has the same life time as its reference_

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lifetime of temporaries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214153/lifetime-of-temporaries) / look what I found

Comment: Hi @LightnessRacesinOrbit. Thank you for your answer but I do not think my question is a duplicate of [Lifetime of temporaries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214153/lifetime-of-temporaries). My question is about a reference. The other question is about function return by value. Please consider both questions are different. Cheers

Comment: @olibre: Yeah, you're right. I must have been drunk.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Please do you know how to remove the header **"This question may already have an answer here"**? (because there is no answer to my question there). Cheers ;-)

Comment: @olibre: [You cannot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166427/automatic-insertion-of-dupe-banner-after-just-one-close-vote-is-vulnerable-to-ab).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Thanks for the link, not yet read everything. Just to inform that two people have down-voted this question, and I do not know how many have cancelled their intention to up-vote. I have an idea: I may edit the top of my question to display a message saying this is not a duplicate message... What do you think about this issue? Cheers ;-)

Comment: @olibre Please don't. Question content is not for meta things. We have these comments and that is enough until the question is closed and re-opened, one day. This is a flaw in SO's mechanism. Anyway, [the banner _only_](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167987/155739) [_appears for you_](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168773/155739).

Comment: Thank you @LightnessRacesinOrbit. You are very pedagogical ;-) It is clear for me. Cheers.

Comment: @olibre Oh I'm something!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How come this is possible?

Because the standard says so, because it's deemed useful. rvalue references and `const` lvalue references extend the lifetime of temporaries:

> `[C++11: 12.2/5]:` *[..]* The temporary to which the reference is bound or the temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound persists
>   for the lifetime of the reference, except *[..]*

and exhaustive wording in `[C++11: 8.5.3/5]` requires that we shall not bind temporaries to non-`const` lvalue references.

---

> Is it specified in the C++ standard?
>   Which version?

Yes. All of them.

Answer (score 6):

A temporary bound to a const reference increases the lifetime of the temporary till the lifetime of the constant reference.

**Good Read:**

***[GotW #88: A Candidate For the “Most Important const”](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/)***

---

Yes it is specified in the C++ standard from the time references were introduced.
So if you are wondering if this is C++11 feature, no it is not. It already existed in C++03.

Answer (score 4):

[Lightness Races in Orbit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560648/lightness-races-in-orbit) is right. And I think this example would be more concise.

```
#include <iostream>  //cout
#include <string>

int main ()
{
    using namespace std;
    int a = 123;
    int b = 123;
//  int       & a_b = a + b; // error!
    int const & a_b = a + b;
    cout<<"hello world!"<<endl;
    cout<<a_b<<endl;
}
```