# Why is it valid to have a reference of the result of string adding if c++17?

Tags: string, c++17

In c++17, it is valid like

```
string s = "asd";
string &ss = "asd" + s;  --> here
```

Now I have two doubts:
1.Why reference of `ss` is valid? What is it reference to? An anonymous variable of the result of
`"asd" + s`?But is it valid to reference to an anonymous variable?
2.Why "asd" could directly add `s`?Wouldn't write it as `string("asd") + s` like before?Why?

Comment: I wouldn't say "valid", please note how some compilers complain about your snippet: https://godbolt.org/z/qh7TKG16T . Also, you may want to look at what [temporary lifetime extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17362673/temporary-lifetime-extension) is.

Comment: Microsoft wins a prize again for being the only compiler that doesn't catch this very basic bug nest, with default command line options.

Comment: Oh.  And "asd" doesn't add s,  the function std::string operator+(const char*, const std::string&) is called.  ss is left holding a reference to a dead r-value.  You just have to **pray** that MS has some kind of proprietary mechanism to keep that alive.  But praying is not considered good coding practice.