# = overloading doesn't work

Tags: c++, visual-c++, operator-overloading

```
#include"stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
class Item
{
 int exponent;
 double coefficient;     //two private members 
 public:
 //constructor
 Item(int exp = 0, int coef = 0) :exponent(exp), coefficient(coef) {}
 Item(Item& item) {
    exponent = item.exponent;
    coefficient = item.coefficient;
 }                                      //copy constructor
 //interface to change private member exponent
 void change_exp(const int n) {           
    Item::exponent = n;
 }
 //interface to change private member coefficient
 void change_coef(const double n) {
    Item::coefficient = n;
 }
 int get_exp() { return exponent; }// interface to get exponent
 double get_coef() { return coefficient; }//  interface to get coefficient
 ~Item() {}
 Item operator=(Item item2) {
    change_exp(item2.get_exp());
    change_coef(item2.get_coef());
    return (*this);
 }
 Item operator*(Item & item2) {
    Item result;
    result.change_coef(coefficient * item2.get_coef());
    result.change_exp(exponent + item2.get_exp());
    return result;
 }
 };
 int main() {
 Item test(2, 7);
 Item test2(4, 5);
 Item result;
 result = test * test2;    //BUG!!! 
 return 0;
 }
```

the bug appears on the line commented BUG
Error   C2679   binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Item' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
when I only assign one object like
    result=test;
it is fine.
I dont know where went wrong in my = overloading function.
Please help......

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [minimal test case](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your copy constructor as `Item(const Item& item)`.

The result of `test * test2` is a temporary rvalue without an address so you can't create a (lvalue) reference to it. It is however allowed to create a const reference.

This question and answer might yield more information related to this topic: [c++: const reference to an rvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112772/c-const-reference-to-an-rvalue)

Answer (score 0):

There are so many things wrong with your code.

- Firstly, you should be respectful to the naming conventions like accessor and mutator methods. You should name your accessor method **setExp** not **change_exp**.
- Secondly, you should know when to overload things like assignment operator (please google **big three in c++**). Basically, you don't have to overload assignment operator if you have only primitive types of fields.
- Lastly, you must use **const** qualifier when ever possible. For example at the end of your accessor methods, in front of the argument for copy contructor, etc..

Your copy constructor should look like

```
Item(const Item& item) {
    exponent = item.exponent;
    coefficient = item.coefficient;
 }
```

Your assignment operator should look like

```
Item& operator=(const Item& item2) {
    change_exp(item2.get_exp());
    change_coef(item2.get_coef());
    return (*this);
 }
```

Your accessor method for field coefficient look like

```
double getCoefficient() const { return coefficient; }//  interface to get coefficient
```