# about returning a const reference to a temporary argument

Tags: c++, linux, stack, g++

I am compiling with g++ 4.8.4 under Ubuntu.

I cannot understand why the code below is working correctly means that prints always on console some output without crashing.

My believe is that the function `foo()` is assigned a temporary object that will last until the function `foo()` finishes its execution.

Surely the output argument will point to the same address on the stack where that temporary has been allocated, but I was surprised to find that each call to `A::hello()` works fine.

I thought that any access to that area of memory should be avoided.

I wanted to double check with 'valgrind' and it is also saying that all is ok. I tried to recompile with `-Wstack-protector` and nothing.

Do you know why it is happening? Is my believe wrong or it is simply one of those 'undefined' C++ behaviour that is best to avoid?

```
 #include <iostream>     
 using namespace std;

 struct A {
    A(): a(10) { cout << "a" << endl;  }
   ~A() {cout << "bye" << endl; }
    void hello() const { cout << "hi " << a << endl; }
 };

 const A& foo(const A& a = A()) {
   return a;
 }

 int main() {
   for( int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
      const A& a = foo();
      a.hello();
   }
   return 0;
 }


 Output
 'a' 
 'bye'
 'hi 10'
 'a' 
 'bye'
 'hi 10'
  ...
```

Comment: Undefined Behaviour can do *anything*, including appearing to work. In this case, the value just doesn't happen to get overwritten before you print it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour is undefined.

Binding a `const` reference to an anonymous temporary extends the lifetime of that anonymous temporary to the lifetime of that `const` reference.

But the attempted re-binding of the returned reference to `a` in `foo` will **not** extend the lifetime: lifetime extension is not *transitive*. So `a` is a *dangling* reference in `main()`.

Comment: do you know whether this behaviour got a name so that I can get collect more info? Still I am a bit puzzled..

Comment: I found enlightment  in two important points I missed http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const and there is another one here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267676/reference-to-an-unnamed-temporary-object-life-time